# Custom View Gone after upgrade android support design library

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a tab layout with custom view

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_tab_host"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#f7f7f7"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:accentColor="@color/primary_color"
    app:hasIcons="true"
    app:iconColor="@color/primary_color"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
    app:primaryColor="#00ffffff"
    app:tabMode="fixed"/>
```

setup it with ViewPager:

```
    // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    // Iterate over all tabs and set the custom view
    for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
        tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
    }
```

I changed the support design library from:

`compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'`

to:

`compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'`

And suddenly custom view is gone :| and just the title of tabs given in the adapter is shown instead. 
Any idea why?

Comment: Could you please also attach the code of your PagerAdapter and the CustomView?